# How to write a WHERE prop FROM value TO value query in Nest JS TypeORM

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I need to find posts from the Post table where price property is either more than 1 value or lower than 2 value, min-max price kind of a thing, how to write a query for that? What should I write into the options object?

Answer (score 0):

```
const posts = await this.postRepo.find({
  where: {
    price: Between(1, 100),
  },
});
```

Can you try this? Or else you can also use createQueryBuilder to write more complex queries.